# how to give an error at the line in my function

Tags: c#, passwords

I've the function that uses a password, when I was running the program, the error in the function does not appear in the message box that I put on the catch, how to give an error on the line that give an error?

```
public void CheckContent(string FileExe, string password)
{
 try
   {
       SevenZipExtractor szip = new SevenZipExtractor(FileExe, password); // <-- error if wrong password  
       foreach (ArchiveFileInfo file in szip.ArchiveFileData)
       {
          string NamaFile = file.FileName;
          string format = file.Extension;
          string[] row;
          row = new string[] { NamaFile, format };
          DGVDekripsi.Rows.Add(row);
       }
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Proses Cek Isi File Exe", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify?

Comment: change `catch(IOException ex)` to `catch(Exception ex)`

Comment: @it's Ok, I running this function, i enter the wrong password, and then the error does not appear as I wrote on the '**catch**', if the error shows the error message in the message box, and the error in line i write the comment '<-- error if wrong password'.

Comment: @Jonesy Right, I missed it, replace with Exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably  the type of throwing exception is different than `IOException`, your catch block will catch only `IOException's`. Try this:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Proses Cek Isi File Exe", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

If you write `ex.GetType()` you will see the type of exception.Then if you wish you can add extra cath block to catch that exception and you can handle it properly.

Comment: Congrats on getting 10k rep :)

Comment: Is it possible to see deleted questions for you like if they're freshly created on the first page? If so how does it look before entering the question? Does it show like a red block?

Comment: @puretppc I didn't see any deleted question.But I can see deleted answers and yes they look like that :)

Comment: @Selman22 Oh I see. What aboout flag reviewing? Where do you get to find them? Sorry for asking you a few things. I don't think I'll ever get 10k since I rarely answer anyways so yeah.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your exception rise? or it's a general exception, did you trace it?
i think you have a normal exception not IOException